# Can you include a signature in a bitcoin payment?

Tags: transactions, signature, message-signing

I know you can use the bitcoin client to sign messages (for which you own the private key) and verify messages from other public addresses. But can you actually embed a signed message into a transaction so its on the blockchain for anyone to verify? When I say "signed message" i'm referring to an arbitrary message like in the attached example.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not possible, although, technically it could be possible by adding `n` child transaction each formed as a tx out of you original transaction. The child transaction then could each have a OP_RETURN (data only) output. With a OP_RETURN output you can store up to 80 bytes (mind [5286](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/5286)). A DER signature will be around [72 Bytes (71.5 in avg)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki#der-encoding)

... so not much to left besides the signature (~8 bytes per OP_RETURN tx as tx out of the original tx). So maybe use OP_RETURN txout `0` to `n-1` for the text/data and `n` for the signature. Obviously this will increase your transaction fee a little because you need at least 2 additional transactions.

**Conclusion:**
Not possible unless your are happy to experiment with forging your own custom transactions.

Comment: Ya looks like OP_RETURN  is the only way to add metadata to a transaction at this point. That's too bad because most wallets don't allow that property to be set, so it would require custom development.